# How to refactor this rails spec?

Tags: ruby, rspec, refactoring

Consider this code snippet:

```
context 'votes' do
  it { should_not be_able_to :vote_yes, create(:question, user: user), user: user }
  it { should be_able_to :vote_yes, create(:question, user: other_user), user: user }
  it { should_not be_able_to :vote_no, create(:question, user: user), user: user }
  it { should be_able_to :vote_no, create(:question, user: other_user), user: user }
  it { should_not be_able_to :reject_vote, create(:question, user: user), user: user }
  it { should be_able_to :reject_vote, create(:question, user: other_user), user: user }

  it { should_not be_able_to :vote_yes, create(:answer, user: user), user: user }
  it { should be_able_to :vote_yes, create(:answer, user: other_user), user: user }
  it { should_not be_able_to :vote_no, create(:answer, user: user), user: user }
  it { should be_able_to :vote_no, create(:answer, user: other_user), user: user }
  it { should_not be_able_to :reject_vote, create(:answer, user: user), user: user }
  it { should be_able_to :reject_vote, create(:answer, user: other_user), user: user }
end
```

How to refactor into something with less lines and duplications?

Answer (score 2):

The first thing I would do is split up your tests into more logical groupings, as it's currently very confusing (at a glance) what the expected behaviour is:

```
context 'voting yes' do
  it { should be_able_to :vote_yes, create(:answer, user: other_user), user: user }
  it { should_not be_able_to :vote_yes, create(:question, user: user), user: user }

  it { should be_able_to :vote_yes, create(:question, user: other_user), user: user }
  it { should_not be_able_to :vote_yes, create(:answer, user: user), user: user }
end

context 'voting no' do
  it { should be_able_to :vote_no, create(:question, user: other_user), user: user }
  it { should_not be_able_to :vote_no, create(:question, user: user), user: user }

  it { should be_able_to :vote_no, create(:answer, user: other_user), user: user }
  it { should_not be_able_to :vote_no, create(:answer, user: user), user: user }
end

context 'rejecting vote' do
  it { should be_able_to :reject_vote, create(:question, user: other_user), user: user }
  it { should_not be_able_to :reject_vote, create(:question, user: user), user: user }

  it { should be_able_to :reject_vote, create(:answer, user: other_user), user: user }
  it { should_not be_able_to :reject_vote, create(:answer, user: user), user: user }
end
```

Looking at this restructured list of tests, it is much easier to see a clear behavioural pattern. You could remove the repetition as follows:

```
%i(vote_yes vote_no reject_vote).each do |action_performed|
  context "can #{action_performed} against other users" do
    it { should be_able_to action_performed, create(:question, user: other_user), user: user }
    it { should be_able_to action_performed, create(:answer, user: other_user), user: user }
  end

  context "cannot #{action_performed} against self" do
    it { should_not be_able_to action_performed, create(:question, user: user), user: user }
    it { should_not be_able_to action_performed, create(:answer, user: user), user: user }
  end 
end
```

You may even be tempted to take this one step further to remove duplication between `question` and `answer` tests:

```
%i(vote_yes vote_no reject_vote).each do |action_performed|
  %i(question answer).each do |record_type|
    it "can #{action_performed} against #{record_type} for other users" do
      should be_able_to action_performed, create(record_type, user: other_user), user: user 
    end

    it "cannot #{action_performed} against #{record_type} for self" do
      should_not be_able_to action_performed, create(record_type, user: user), user: user
    end
  end
end
```

However, this probably makes the tests *harder* to understand and edit, so I'd advise against it... Maybe if that list of record types (`question`, `answer`, `...`) grows much longer, then you could consider an approach like this.

Comment: Also for future reference, questions like this are better suited to the [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) StackExchange site.